# Brand New iPhone 6 and Refubrished

Tags: iphone

I am thinking to Purchase iPhone 6. The problem is that in my country there are no Apple Stores. I need to purchase it through shops who import iPhone's from UK or USA. My friends are telling me that iPhone's that are sold in some shops are Refurbished or opened to replace original parts with duplicate that are similar to original. 
The cost of an iPhone 6 16GB in my country is around £480 or $750 which is comparatively high than original price on which iPhone are sold in Apple Stores.

I do not want to waste my money on purchasing a refurbished or repaired iPhone. I want to ask that is there any way to detect that the iPhone have been opened or it is refurbished?

Comment: well, you wont know that unitl after you have the phone in your hands. can you return it in case of ?

Comment: If they do a good job refurbishing it, you would not be able to tell it was opened. If the shell of the phone has any cosmetic imperfections, it is likely used, but even that is not a guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you buy an new iPhone it is not used before and sealed. The only ways to get an refurbished iPhone is via the apple online store or when you have damaged your device.

Apple doesn't repair the iPhone when you send it in. Instead they will give you back an refurbished iPhone.
After that they repair your iPhone and will use it for another client.

Comment: "The only ways to get an refurbished iPhone is via the apple online store or when you have damaged your device." This is not true. Anybody can "refurbish" an iPhone and resell it. The question then would be how good of a job they did, what was wrong originally, if it was actually fixed, et cetera.

Comment: The only way to get an refurbished device from apple is by buying it online on their website or when you bring your damaged phone to an authorised service provider

Comment: Repeating what you already stated does not make it any more true. You are conflating _Apple_ refurbished devices with _all_ refurbished devices. Even then, one can buy a device that was previously refurbished by Apple from a third-party as well.